# Importing FoxPro tables into SQL using C# - One table works, one doesn't

Tags: c#, sql, foxpro

I'm working some methods to import data from FoxPro tables and write it to SQL tables.  This is just a tiny chunk of an enterprise-class application, and frankly most of it is over my head.  The method I'm having problems with gets two FoxPro tables and puts them in Datasets.  The first table comes over no problem, but the second keeps coming up empty.  Here's my code (more details after the code):

```
public DataSet GetFoxProDelinquencyData()
    {
        DataSet bothDlqTables = new DataSet();
        DataSet DlqData;
        string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM MasterDlqTable";

        try
        {
            DlqData = _foxProServiceAccess.ExecuteFoxProDataSet(selectQuery, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionToHandle)
        {
            throw ExceptionHelper.HandleFoxProException(exceptionToHandle,
                            "Failed to get data from FoxPro");
        }

        DlqData.Tables[0].TableName = "Master";
        bothDlqTables.Tables.Add(DlqData.Tables[0].Copy());
        string delqnum = Convert.ToString(bothDlqTables.Tables[0].Rows[0]["delqnum"]);
        selectQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM rvdlqhst_txps WHERE delqnum = '{0}'", delqnum);

        try
        {
            DlqData = _foxProServiceAccess.ExecuteFoxProDataSet(selectQuery, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionToHandle)
        {
            throw ExceptionHelper.HandleFoxProException(exceptionToHandle,
                            "Failed to get data from FoxPro");
        }

        DlqData.Tables[0].TableName = "History";
        bothDlqTables.Tables.Add(DlqData.Tables[0].Copy());
        return bothDlqTables;
    }
```

So, when I'm debugging and I look at the content of bothDlqTables just before the return at the end, the Master table is perfect, and the History table has the correct columns from its FoxPro equivalent, but it has no data.  Same with the DlqData dataset.  The delqnum string contains 000210 and our dB guy confirms that the FoxPro table definitely contains records with that delinquency number.  When he runs

```
SELECT * FROM rvdlqhst_txps WHERE delqnum = '000210'
```

from within the database viewer, he gets results.  I've tried hard-coding that SELECT statement as a string instead of the string.format command, and I still get the same empty table.  Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I'm also getting an intermittent error on the first query of:

Could not connect to net.tcp://rdsfoxproqa.alatax.com/FoxProService_Dist. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0625340. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 172.19.0.105:808.

It happens from time to time, and often I can just wait 30 min or so and then try again and the query works.  I don't think this is related, but I also don't know what's causing it and would love to.

Comment: Have you tried trimming any possible extraneous spaces off of delqnum after the first copy operation? You might find that the value there is something like ' 000210' and causing your headache...

Comment: Well, I'm in debug mode, so I can see the exact content of the string, and it's "000210".  There was a period where I thought maybe it was a different datatype in the history table, so I needed to remove the leading zeroes, but I have since confirmed in the database viewer that the column is a VARCHAR type and all the values are 6 digits with 2-3 leading zeroes.  But thank you for the suggestion, I really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: OK...then here's another shot in the dark....try changing your delimiter in the second SELECT statement from '{0}' to "{0}" and see if that makes a difference...used to work in FoxPro a looooooooooong time ago, that might help..?

Comment: Tried changing to "{0}" (well, actually \"{0}\" of course) but it didn't work.  Good shot though!

Comment: Wow, thought sure we were gonna sneak past the guard on that one :) The next thing that occurs to me is some sort of padding or encoding issue on the FoxPro side...can you post the exact declaration of that field from your table? I'm looking for any chance the delqnum field has some unusual encoding or mandatory minimum length or ??? associated with it... Does your _foxProServiceAccess layer support parameterized queries, such that you could rewrite the query and eliminate the string literal portion entirely?

Comment: I don't have the declaration, but in FoxPro Table Designer the Name is delqnum, the Type is Character, and the Width is 6.  The Decimal, Index, and NULL fields of table designer are empty.  I'm looking into the ServiceAccess layer now.  I'm a little dubious, because I've tried hard-coding the SELECT statement with '000210' instead of the literal, and had the same result.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I bet you'll find the problem in there somewhere,  a truncated character, or some other evil you'd never expect....

Comment: What does _foxProServiceAccess use to talk to the VFP data?

Comment: Alan, I'm not sure.  I found this definition...       

(I can't line breaks to work in these comments, so code is between asterisks)***
public string ExecuteFoxProReader(string sqlQuery, int instanceId) {
            return base.Channel.ExecuteFoxProReader(sqlQuery, instanceId);
        }  ***



       ...Does that help?

Comment: @JeremyShapiro - Are there any records in the rvdlqhst_txps table marked as deleted? If they are, the ODBC and OLEDB drivers I have used ignore those records and I need to send a SET DELETED OFF command before the SQL SELECT command.

Comment: I don't see any such flags in Visual FoxPro, no.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I don't know about your _foxProServiceAccess object... is it a wrapper class going around Visual Foxpro tables?  Is it using ODBC connection or Microsoft's latest VFP OleDB provider to get the data.  Is the connection using "DBase" connection vs explicit VFP OleDB?  And finally, parameterized queries would be better approach... I haven't had any problems when using M$ VFP OleDB provider for the years I've done connection to VFP from .net...

Answer (score 1):

If DaveB's answer does not help: if you remove the WHERE clause completely, do you then get some data?  That might help towards finding the cause of the problem.

Comment: If I remove the WHERE clause completely, the request times out after 10 minutes.  If I change the statement to SELECT * ... ... WHERE delqnum > '000209', I get a table where every tuple has a delqnum of '000211', which makes no sense to me at all.